# How to put one cartoon in the background of one book

Tags: formatting, diagrams, backgrounds

I would like to add one cartoon in the right margin of odd pages in one book. More precisely, ...

- ... the page #1 must contain the picture #1,
- ... the page #3 must contain the picture #2,
- ... the page #5 must contain the picture #3,
- ... and so on.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can include the pictures using `\includegraphics`.

In order to ensure to get one cartoon per page, I would call it from the header rendering, using `\srcpage2` for example.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\cartoon}[1]{%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(#1,-200){\includegraphics[width=35mm]{xkcd/\thepage.jpg}}
\end{picture}
}
\cehead[\cartoon{-320}]{}
\cohead[\cartoon{220}]{}
\pagestyle{scrplain}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument   
\end{document}
```

And the result, alternating margins:

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

[image: Page 3]

**Edit:** Upon re-reading your question, I just saw you only wanted odd margins. Just remove the `\cehead` and you'll only have odd margins.

Comment: Hello. Can you be a little more precise ?

Comment: I'm preparing an example :-)

Comment: Oh, just saw odd margins...

Comment: You may have to use `\the\numexpr\thepage/2\relax` as the figure number, depending on the precise specification.

Comment: @Bruno: right, I didn't take into consideration the fact that numbers are skipped if only odd margins are used :-)

Comment: Hello, thanks for all. One last small question about \the\numexpr\thepage/2\relax. Where must I put it ?

Comment: @projetmbc: use it instead of `\thepage` in my code.

Comment: @projetmbc: note you can use backticks to display code on this website.

Comment: I've found : I have to use `\put(#1,-200){\includegraphics[width=35mm]{picture/{\the\numexpr\thepage/2\relax}.jpg}}` instead of `\put(#1,-200){\includegraphics[width=35mm]{picture/\thepage.jpg}}`

Comment: @projetmbc: that's exactly what I meant. If my answer fixes your issue, feel free to select it.

Comment: The problem I met is that I first used `\the\numexpr\thepage/2\relax` that did not worked contrary to `{\the\numexpr\thepage/2\relax}`. Thanks for all !!!