# Animation on paper

Tags: margins, animations

I started writing my thesis and someone proposed that I could put small markings on the edge of the pages so that when someone flips the pages an animation would be shown.

I would like to have the animation done in `PSTricks` or `TikZ` or another format (e.g. `.gif`) and then specify in the preamble that there is going to be an animation in pages `x-y` and indicate the animation (either a `.gif` or a `.pdf`) and maybe where in the margin it will take place.

Is there a package doing something close to that?

Has anyone done something similar with other tools?

Comment: Maybe this thread in comp.text.tex can help: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/comp.text.tex/flip$20pages$20animation/comp.text.tex/OfORB47aVUQ/DlzlR5BDcd4J

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26969/1952

Comment: also related: [flip book in master thesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57997/579).  the last answer gives a link to a `flipbook` package on ctan.

Comment: @Ignasi The first link gives me an `invalid input` error. The second seems relevant for a manual implementation

Comment: @barbarabeeton Looks like if I combine `flipbook` with the second link of Ignasi, I will be on my way for my own implementation.